# I'm missing the ties for the other nodes in my network and I'm unsure why, any help would be much appreciated

Tags: r, igraph, sna

My code is the following:

```
D_igraph <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices = nodes, directed = FALSE)
as.numeric(Strength1)
set.graph.attribute(D_igraph, "Strength_of_tie", Strength1)
D
E(D_igraph)$Strength <- Strength1
plot(D_igraph, vertex.label.color="black",
     edge.color=c("yellow","pink", "green","blue", "violet"))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Okay sure thing, thanks.

Comment: Essentially i have an edge attribute variable, Strength, which i want to color code based on the strength value (1,2,3,4,5) in the igraph but am unsure how to do this. it is currently coded as a character edge attribute for the vertex (nodes) which are schools. It looks like "1" "5" "3" etc for all 49 or so ties. Any help would be great!

Comment: tie_type_colors = c("yellow", "violet", "skyblue", "pink", "green")
E(D_igraph)$Strength[ E(D_igraph)$Strength==1 ] = tie_type_colors[1]
E(D_igraph)$Strength[ E(D_igraph)$Strength==2 ] = tie_type_colors[2]
E(D_igraph)$Strength[ E(D_igraph)$Strength==3 ] = tie_type_colors[3]
E(D_igraph)$Strength[ E(D_igraph)$Strength==4 ] = tie_type_colors[4]
E(D_igraph)$Strength[ E(D_igraph)$Strength==5 ] = tie_type_colors[5]


plot(D_igraph)